# localhost doesn't work when I dockerize postgres with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, ubuntu, localserver

My system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

I was going through the Django for professionals book and follow all line by line but somehow when i dockerize my django project with postgres it just doesn't run localhost properly, with sqlite all works fine.

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.6-slim-bullseye
# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code
# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copy project
COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
 web:
  build: .
  command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  ports:
   - 8000:8000
  depends_on:
   - db
 db:
  image: postgres:13
  volumes:
   - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  environment:
   - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
 postgres_data:
```

django.settings.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",  # set in docker-compose.yml
        "PORT": 5432,  # default postgres port
    }
}
```

When I run `docker-compose up` that shows and seems like all must be fine, but somehow it just doesn't work:

```
Attaching to ch3-postgresql_web_1, ch3-postgresql_db_1
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | 
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2022-12-05 11:58:21.572 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.9 (Debian 13.9-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1   | 2022-12-05 11:58:21.574 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2022-12-05 11:58:21.575 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2022-12-05 11:58:21.577 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2022-12-05 11:58:21.580 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-12-05 11:58:17 UTC
db_1   | 2022-12-05 11:58:21.584 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

And when I go to the url `127.0.0.1:8000`:

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

If i wait some time and then check `docker-compose logs`, this messages appears

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "db" (172.21.0.2), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
web_1  |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I spend a lot of hours of searching for info about this problem but nothing did help. I try even to reinstall different versions of Postgres and docker.

Comment: have you installed psycopg2

Comment: i did, but psycopg2-binary like in the book i follow

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the output of your process in the question.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the final two links with the relevant output messages, as plain text, and directly in the question?  When you "go to the localhost", what URL exactly are you connecting to, and from where?

Comment: @DavidMaze i've edited as you asked

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

change this:

```
volumes:
   - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

To this:

```
volumes:
   - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data #removed forward slash from here.
```

Try above thing and see if it solves that problem.

Note: after making above changes don't forget to re-build docker-compsoe

Comment: i have just tried, it doen't work(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add more environment variables to make the PostgreSQL work.

Please refer to https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres "Environment Variables"

> The only variable required is `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, the rest are optional.

```yaml
db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

And, you are encouraged to make your docker compose file more secure:

```yaml
db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
```

.env.dev

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```